# What do I need to leave out of Git for Eclipse CDT Projects

Tags: c, eclipse, git, metadata, gitignore

I have a project that has it's include files pretty much in the project folder...I don't use anything that's in, say, `/usr/lib`...It's all in `./whatever`.

I'd like to share a project, with the intent that people will import it into Eclipse and then will be able to go from there.  However, this never works right, because when I push changes, my environment variables get pushed too.  This breaks other peoples projects when the pull from Git.

What do I need to exclude from revision tracking to make sure that the environment variables don't get changed with each remote push, but that things like new Include Paths do?

Thanks

Comment: This question is tagged with "C" but there is no part related to C at all.

Comment: I didn't know if there would be a difference between a C project metadata with Eclipse vs., say, a Java projects metadata.  That's why the C tag is there.

Comment: Github [hosts a nice collection of .gitignore templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore).  Might want to check there and see if they have one for your project type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, do not include

```
.project
.cproject
.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.prefs   <- CDT support stuff
.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs   <- file encodings
.settings/org.eclipse.core.runtime.prefs     <- line terminators
```

in .gitignore. This will reduce the fidelity of importing your project within your team. Files to consider including:

```
.buildpath                            <- system specifics
.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.core.prefs  <- system specifics
```

I truly wish CDT was a bit more relocatable friendly (using 6.0 and 8.8).

Good luck

Randall
(Git platform maintainer for NonStop)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the unwanted files to your [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file. For eclipse I believe your .gitignore must look like

```
.project
.buildpath
```

Comment: Well.. `.project` might contain some non-obvious configuration in case it is not a Makefile project..

Comment: ...Are you sure about the `.project`?  That makes it un-import-able

Comment: @BrocolliRob Well, when they pull the project, they can import it manually and their copy of eclipse will generate its own `.project`. All said and done everyone has their own `.project` file thus no one is sharing environment variables.

Comment: doesn't .cproject contain direct references to path variables as well as include statements?

Comment: @BrocolliRob off the top of my head I don't remember. I will share with you that when it comes to C projects its almost 99% better to make your own makefile. That's what I do with my projects and when I share them I don't have any issues with importing variables and such.